# How some dll file cannot be found when launching illustrator with wine in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, wine, adobe-illustrator

I copied illustrator directory from windows system to the wine "Program files directory" in CentOS 7 system and tried to launch illustrator with wine. I give the following command in centos 7 terminal:

```
"~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Adobe/Adobe\ Illustrator\ CC\ 2018/Support\ Files/Contents/Windows/Illustrator.exe"
```

However, I get the following error:

```
0009:err:module:import_dll Loading library gdiplus.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\Illustrator.exe") failed (error c000007b).
0009:err:module:import_dll Loading library gdiplus.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\dvaui.dll") failed (error c000007b).
0009:err:module:import_dll Library dvaui.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\Illustrator.exe") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Loading library gdiplus.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\dvaai.dll") failed (error c000007b).
0009:err:module:import_dll Loading library gdiplus.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\dvaui.dll") failed (error c000007b).
0009:err:module:import_dll Library dvaui.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\dvaai.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Loading library gdiplus.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\dvaui.dll") failed (error c000007b).
0009:err:module:import_dll Library dvaui.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\dvaadameve.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library dvaadameve.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\dvaai.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Loading library gdiplus.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\dvaui.dll") failed (error c000007b).
0009:err:module:import_dll Library dvaui.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\dvaworkspace.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library dvaworkspace.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\dvaai.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Loading library gdiplus.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\exo.dll") failed (error c000007b).
0009:err:module:import_dll Loading library gdiplus.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\dvaui.dll") failed (error c000007b).
0009:err:module:import_dll Library dvaui.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\exo.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Loading library gdiplus.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\dvaui.dll") failed (error c000007b).
0009:err:module:import_dll Library dvaui.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\dvaworkspace.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library dvaworkspace.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\exo.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library exo.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\dvaai.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Loading library gdiplus.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\dvaui.dll") failed (error c000007b).
0009:err:module:import_dll Library dvaui.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\dvametadataUI.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Loading library gdiplus.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\dvaui.dll") failed (error c000007b).
0009:err:module:import_dll Library dvaui.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\dvaeve.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library dvaeve.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\dvametadataUI.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library dvametadataUI.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\dvaai.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Loading library gdiplus.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\AdobeOwl.dll") failed (error c000007b).
0009:err:module:import_dll Library AdobeOwl.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\dvaai.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library dvaai.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\Illustrator.exe") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Loading library gdiplus.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\dvaui.dll") failed (error c000007b).
0009:err:module:import_dll Library dvaui.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\dvaworkspace.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library dvaworkspace.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\Illustrator.exe") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Loading library gdiplus.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\exo.dll") failed (error c000007b).
0009:err:module:import_dll Loading library gdiplus.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\dvaui.dll") failed (error c000007b).
0009:err:module:import_dll Library dvaui.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\exo.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Loading library gdiplus.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\dvaui.dll") failed (error c000007b).
0009:err:module:import_dll Library dvaui.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\dvaworkspace.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library dvaworkspace.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\exo.dll") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library exo.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\Illustrator.exe") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Loading library gdiplus.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\AdobeSplashKit.dll") failed (error c000007b).
0009:err:module:import_dll Library AdobeSplashKit.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\Illustrator.exe") not found
0009:err:module:attach_dlls Importing dlls for L"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\\Support Files\\Contents\\Windows\\Illustrator.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

I found that the some dll libraries (such as gdiplus.dll) not found are actually in the directory , while other dll libraries are really missing.

So how to let wine find the exiting dll for illustrator? How to assign the path of dll for wine?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to open the command prompt in wine, then in that cmd window open Adobe Illustrator. Though [Adobe Illustrator CC 2018](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=20) is not in wine app database.

Comment: I tried to launch illustrator in wine cmd, but the same error information comes out.